# How to find a substring of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, recursion

I just started learning about recursion in python and I'm having trouble when to return a function call or just return a condition. Can you help me figure out the problem I'm having in this program, can't see what is going wrong.

```
def prefix(sub, a_string, i=1):
    '''Prefix looks for a substring by checking ex. if el is in hello by first
    checking h == el then he == el... hello == el. If not then cut out the first letter
    and start again. e == el then el == el and should then return'''
    if len(a_string) == i:
        is_substring(sub, a_string[1:])
    if sub == a_string[0:i]: # Then we have found a substring
       return True
    else:
       prefix(sub, a_string, i+1)

def is_substring(sub, a_string):
    #Checks for base condition
    if sub == "" or a_string == "":
        return False
    return prefix(sub, a_string)

#print(is_substring("el", "hello"))
```

Comment: I suggest that you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging. Use its tips to get a better understanding of what your code is doing. If you still need help, please give the output of your code and explain what you would like it to do differently.

Comment: You need to make sure `prefix` is returning something in all branches. It's not currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `is_substring` and `prefix` but don't return their result, you need to add some `return`

```
def prefix(sub, a_string, i=1):
    if len(a_string) == i:
        return is_substring(sub, a_string[1:])
    if sub == a_string[0:i]: # Then we have found a substring
       return True
    else:
       return prefix(sub, a_string, i+1)
```

Also add the basic equality condition in `is_substring`

```
def is_substring(sub, a_string):
    if sub == "" or a_string == "":
        return False
    if sub == a_string:
      return True
    return prefix(sub, a_string)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! and also the solution makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble when to return a function call or just return a condition.

In recursion, you "just return a condition" when you can immediately know the answer. This is called the "base case". For example, you have

if sub == "" or a_string == "":
    return False

Here it is simple to check what the return value should be.

Similarly, you can check this very easily:

```
if sub == a_string[0:i]: # Then we have found a substring
   return True
```

I suspect that the problem is with the order of your `if` statements. Typically we put the base case first, because it will return immediately.